# A greasemonkey script to move interesting tags to top, ignored tags to bottom

Tags: discussion, tags, userscript

I've just created a small Greasemonkey script which will move interesting tags to the top, and ignored tags to the bottom.

You can get the script from the User Scripts page: [https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/54938](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/54938)

**EDIT:** Updated to work in Chrome and Firefox. Supports all SE sites.

Comment: I'm guessing that ones tagged as neither go in the middle?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Glad to see others hopping onto the GreaseMonkey-Train :)

Comment: I keep trying to google this as "sort interesting" so now the page has the word "sort" and I will find it!

Comment: can this please be moved to http://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts as necessary? Or flag for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd love to see ignored tags complete removed from the page. I only ignore the topics I really dislike.

Edit: or atleast put them in a group and collapse them.

Comment: **@CasperT:** That's already a feature in SO. Click on your name, then click on *prefs*. There you have a checkmark called *Hide Ignored Tags*.